# PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/lib64/php/modules/redis.so'を解消したい

Tags: php, redis

redisをphpredisから使おうとしたところ

```
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/lib64/php/modules/redis.so' - /usr/lib64/php/modules/redis.so: undefined symbol: igbinary_serialize in Unknown on line 0
```

が表示されます。

```
<?php
$redis = new Redis();
$redis->connect('127.0.0.1', 6379);

echo $redis->ping();
?>
```

のphp(test.php)ですが、実行すると

```
# php test.php
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/lib64/php/modules/redis.so' - /usr/lib64/php/modules/redis.so: undefined symbol: igbinary_serialize in Unknown on line 0
+PONG
```

で、一応PONGは返ってくるようです。

環境は、
PHP 7.0.27 (cli) (built: Jan  2 2018 12:38:03) ( NTS )
redis-cli 3.2.10

/etc/php.iniには

```
extension_dir = "/usr/lib64/php/modules"
[redis]
extension=redis.so
```

を追記しています。

モジュールの重複設定かと疑いましたが、

```
# more /etc/php.ini | grep redis
[redis]
extension=redis.so
```

で重複はしていない模様。

動作はしている(?Warningだけ)模様なので、気にすることはないかもしれませんが、このWarningを消す（解消）するにはどうしたらいいのでしょうか。
ご存知の方、ご教示お願いします。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

「undefined symbol: igbinary_serialize」（"igbinary_serialize"が定義されていません）というワーニングなのですから、igbinary_serializeが含まれているライブラリを導入すれば解決すると思われます。

[【メモ】redisをphpで使うまで](https://qiita.com/shinofara/items/9476cee35cfac1b7ee50)の記事で、「Memcached 拡張内でおこなわれるシリアライズ処理の最適化のために igbinary 拡張を導入します」と書かれている辺りが参考になるのではないでしょうか。